# MySQL Left Join bigger than the "left" table alone?

Tags: mysql

Am I understanding what Left Join is supposed to do?

I have a query. Call it Query A.  It returns 19 records.

I have another query, Query B. It returns 1,400 records.

I insert Query B into Query A as a left join, so Query A becomes:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA
LEFT JOIN (<<entire SQL of Query B>>) ON tableA.id = tableB.id
```

Now, a Left Join means everything from Table A, and only records from Table B where they match.  So no matter what, this mixed query should not return more than the 19 records that the original Query A returns.  What I actually get is 1,000 records.

Am I fundamentally misunderstanding how LEFT JOIN works?

Comment: What is the relationship between `tableA` and tableB`? Your result set sounds correct if `tableA` has a _one-to-many_ relationship to `tableB`.

Comment: For instance 3 x 3 = 9

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're not exactly misunderstanding `LEFT JOIN`, so much as the results implied by it. If you have only one row in A, and 1000 in B that reference to the id of that single row in A; your result will be 1000 rows. *You're overlooking that the relation may be 1-to-many.* The size of the "left" table/subquery (subject to `WHERE` conditions) is the **lower bound** for the number of results.

Comment: Ah... this may be exactly what I needed.  So I'm going to need something like DISTINCT or GROUP BY to tighten things down, perhaps.

Comment: Other answer was useful as well; but this was first, and gave me what I needed.  Thanks

Comment: @StephenR the functionality of `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` are no more (or less) useful in this situation than in an `INNER JOIN` or even a simple single-table `SELECT`.

Comment: I actually resolved it by modifying the "ON" clause of the JOIN.  But your post definitely led me in the right direction (or more specifically, stopped me looking in the wrong direction!)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you are misunderstanding slightly.

> Now, a Left Join means everything from Table A, and only records from Table B where they match.

So far, so good: the data from Table B will be included only if it matches against Table A according to the rules you specify in the `ON` clause.

> So no matter what, this mixed query should not return more than the 19 records that the original Query A returns.

This seems like it makes sense, until you realise that **more than one row in Table B can match the same row in Table A**.

Let's say you have 2 rows in Table A, one with `A_ID=1` and one with `A_ID=3`; and 10 rows in Table B; 5 of the rows in Table B have `A_ID=1`, and 5 have `A_ID=2`. All the rows in Table B have different values for `B_ID`.

If you use a Left Join with the condition that `A_ID` must match, which rows will you get?

- The row from Table A with `A_ID=3` will show up once, with a `NULL` value for `B_ID`, because there is no row in Table B to match it.
- The 5 rows from Table B with `A_ID=2` won't show up at all, because they don't match any rows from Table A.
- The 5 rows from Table B with `A_ID=1` will **all** show up, each partnered with the 1 row from Table A with `A_ID=1`.

So you get 6 results, even though there were only 2 rows in Table A.